# How to set value of multiple select in materializecss and angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, select, materialize

I'm using the materializecss select with multiple attribute. When, I'm able to read selected values from it, there's no way to set selected values in it, from angular or javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find all the checkboxes with option you want to activate and invoke click()